# drawing to a JPanel without inheritance

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Right now I'm working on a program that throws up a bunch of separate (generated at runtime) images, each in their own window.  To do this i've tried this approach:

```
public void display(){
    JFrame window = new JFrame("NetPart");
    JPanel canvas = new JPanel();
    window.getContentPane().add(canvas);
    Graphics g = canvas.getGraphics();
    Dimension d = getSize();
    System.out.println(d);
    draw(g,new Point(d.minX*50,d.maxY*50), 50);
    window.setSize(d.size(50));
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.HIDE_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setVisible(true);
}

public void draw(Graphics g, Point startLoc, int scale){
    // generate and draw the image
}

public Dimension getSize(){
    //returns my own dimensions class
}
```

However, this throws a NullPointerException in draw, claiming that the graphics is null.  is there any way to externally draw to a JPanel from outside it (not inherit from JPanel and override PaintComponent)?  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are drawing your images at runtime you should use BufferedImage.

Create a BufferedImage, call getGraphics() on it to get its Graphics object, draw to it using the Graphics(2D) api, then call Graphics.dispose() (not strictly necessary but a good habit) and as the previous poster suggested either create an ImageIcon with it and put in a JLabel using setIcon() or subclass JPanel / JComponent and draw it in paintComponent

Comment: How do I draw the BufferedImage to the JPanel, though?

Comment: To draw the BufferedImage on the JPanel you would need to subclass JPanel and call g.drawImage(myBufferedImage, x, y, ...) within the paintComponent method

Answer (score 4):

You're finding out that `getGraphics()` won't work in this way since the Graphics object obtained is null prior to the component being rendered, and even when it is not null, it is not stable and becomes invalid with each redraw.  Possible options include:

- Creating ImageIcon from each Image, placing the icon in a JLabel and displaying the JLabel.
- Biting the bullet and extending JPanel or other JComponent (you don't say why you're trying to avoid this) and displaying the image in the JPanel's paintComponent method.
- Doing the above, but first creating a BufferedImage which is displayed in the `paintComponent(...)` method. Then you can modify the BufferedImage during the program's run if you need to change the display, add new images,...

Comment: the images i'm using are generated at runtime, so i (as far as i know) can't make an imageIcon.  the reason I don't want to extend JPanel is that my code is actually for generating the structure behind the images, and displaying them is mostly just a useful utility (before this I used a complicated toString, but it got to the point that I couldn't understand it, so I created this.  How would one create a BufferedImage to display?

Comment: @g.rocket: your assumption about not being able to make an ImageIcon during run-time is wrong, and this should make sense, since why would a running application prevent a class from being created? I see that the "accepted" answer was the same as my 3rd bullet point above.

Comment: I know you can make a ImageIcon from an image file (sitting on the hard drive) at run time, but as far as I know I can't do custom drawing to an ImageIcon, which is what I am trying to do

Comment: yes it was just about the same, but it explained more how to do so, which I didn't understand

Comment: @g.rocket: Again, I'm not sure what you mean by "you can't to custom drawing to an ImageIcon". Sure you can -- you can do any type of custom drawing that you'd like. An ImageIcon is based on an Image. If you draw to a BufferedImage "during runtime", you can create an ImageIcon at any time from that image.

Answer (score 2):

```
a program that throws up a bunch of separate (generated at runtime) images, 
each in their own window
```

1. don't do it that this way, don't create a lots of `JFrames`, these `Object` stays in the memory, until current JVM instance exists, result from this concept pretty could be `OutOfMemory exceptions`
2. don't create lots of `JFrames`, create only one `JFrame`, rest of `Containers` could be `JDialog` or `JWindow`
3. don't create a new `JFrames`, `JDialogs` or `JWindows` on the runtime, re_use the existing `Containers`
4. put these images as [Icon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/icon.html)s to the [JList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) or maybe better would be look at [CardLayout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html)